# Making classes focus on doing one thing - practically

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

This is again, more of a conceptual question (see previous post [Is there a difference between Object and Models in PHP/CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718698/is-there-a-difference-between-object-and-models-in-php-codeigniter))

This is CodeIgniter (an MVC framework) on PHP.

I'm trying to work out the best ( = practical, and sound principles) way to implement this example.

In my example, in the database schema, since I am using tank_auth on codeigniter, a table called "users" has been created automatically for me (by tank_auth). So this one user table represents all my users in whatever role in my book lending library application.

A person could fill numerous roles simultaneously (lender, author, librarian, manager, etc). I had initially started out thinking I should have a "people_model" (as the M in MVC) but am now wondering if it is not better to do it like this:

There should be a "lender" model and a "author" model and a "librarian" model etc. I'm hard pressed to explain why it make sense, but it is probably because  of the OOP principle "make classes focus on doing one thing (Single Responsibility)".

So is this example what that principle refers to? My "librarian" class (model) should only have librarian functions. Anything more is just one step too far removed, and having a "people" class in general that does everything that would be done by a "real person" is just too abstract?... am I on the right track here? I'll have to do a bit of re-engineering... but that's the learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on what your users do, and how different their roles are.  Chances are that all users have more things in common than things that differentiate them.

You should probably start with a single model that deals with basic user functions.  If there are a bunch of specific db calls that you need to make for different users then you can build out additional, user type specific models.  However I would not start with that since it is almost definitely a path to having to write and maintain more code (and likely some duplicate code) rather than less.

Comment: Do I understand correctly your advice or approach correctly? Start with a single "people" class that covers all db calls / functions that are needed, even if they are unique. If they grow a lot, then consider breaking them out into their own model. So it could happen that way down the line I have a "librarian" model and a "manager" model, which have their own unique functions/calls, but at the same time call the common functions like "loan_book()" in this initial "people" class, which remains relevant to *all* people (i.e. users). Sounds pretty reasonable.

Comment: Yes, there are probably a lot of things that are shared between users, and if you start with the mentality that you're going to create a unique model for each user you will likely end up writing duplicate code.